# Operators === and ||

Tags: javascript, operators

I wonder, are these absolutely the same:

```
var a = something1.something2 === undefined ? 1 : something1.something2;
var b = something1.something2 || 1;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  In the first one, `something1.something2` *has* to be `undefined` in order to get the value `1`.  In the second one it merely has to be falsy. There are lots of [falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy): `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, and of course, `false`.

Comment: @deceze: No, the more efficient way to deal with it is find whoever redefined `undefined` as something other than `undefined` and beat them about the head and shoulders with cold, wet spaghetti until they come to their senses.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, oh my God, you're a beast. A very kind beast.

Comment: @deceze Not in HTML5 context... undefined is read-only there.

Answer (score 0):

No they are not.

If you take the value `0` for `something1.something2`, then in the first case the return value is `0`.

The second case returns `1`, because of the falsy value of `0`.